# Prestashop 1.7, error on translated pages

Tags: translation, prestashop-1.7

I'm having a weird issue here.

Everytime I try to access my prestashop 1.7 website in another language than the default one (EN atm), I get a blank page.

I enabled the debug mode and this is the error I'm receiving :

```
ContextErrorException in ApiClient.php line 52:
Notice: Undefined offset: 1
```

It's even more weird that I've created a custom module and there's no error in any other languages on my module's pages.

has anyone already faced this problem?  I'm really struggling here.

Thank's !

[EDIT] :

I managed to get it working, by reinstalling a new PS 1.7.2.2 .. Had to reinstall a lot of other things so this isn't the best option but now at least it works.  I don't know what I've done on the previous version to break everything because I actually repeated the same steps here :/

Comment: It seems you're not alone ... https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/629298-solved-error-500-when-changing-language-from-swedish-to-english/
http://forge.prestashop.com/browse/BOOM-3857
You will have to wait for a bug fix or fix it yourself.

Comment: Yeah I've seen this too but I'm not sure if it's a bug of something wrong I did/forgot :s